# jQuery get list of checked checkboxes with specific class to array

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox

I'm trying to get the list of checked checkboxes with specific class attribute and put their values to array. I want to use it to enable / disable select menu. So far I have the following, which doesn't seem to work for me:

```
<select name="inboxSelect" id="inboxSelect" class="selectDisabledSwitch" data-trigger="selectTrigger" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="">With selected</option>
    <option value="1">Archive</option>
    <option value="2">Mark as completed</option>
</select>


<input type="checkbox" name="inbox-1" id="inbox-1" value="1" class="selectTrigger" />
<input type="checkbox" name="inbox-2" id="inbox-2" value="2" class="selectTrigger" />
<input type="checkbox" name="inbox-3" id="inbox-3" value="3" class="selectTrigger" />
```

and javascript / jquery:

```
var frontObject = {
    getCheckboxCheckedArray : function(objClass) {
        var thisArray = $('input:checkbox:checked.' + objClass).map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get();
        return thisArray;
    },
    selectDisabledSwitch : function(obj) {
        if (obj.length > 0) {
            var thisObj = $(this);
            var thisTrigger = thisObj.attr('data-trigger'); 
            var thisValues = frontObject.getCheckboxCheckedArray(thisTrigger);
            frontObject.disableMenu(thisObj, thisValues);
            $('.' + thisTrigger).live('change', function() {
                var thisValues = frontObject.getCheckboxCheckedArray(thisTrigger);
                frontObject.disableMenu(thisObj, thisValues);
            });
        }
    },
    disableMenu : function(thisObj, thisValues) {
        if (thisValues.length > 0) {
            thisObj.attr('disabled', false);
        } else {
            thisObj.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }
};
$(function() {
    frontObject.selectDisabledSwitch($('.selectDisabledSwitch'));
});
```

Sorry - just to clarify - I want the select to be disabled if none of the checkboxes with the specific class is checked and remove disabled attribute when at least one is checked.

Comment: a jsfiddle of the problem, always helps! http://jsfiddle.net/2Wnv4/ and Im unclear about the question: you want to disable select when a specific checkbox is checked? Like when checkbox 1 is checked it is disabled?

Comment: Hi Hans - I've added the clarification under the main post - sorry it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change

```
var thisObj = $(this);
```

with

```
var thisObj = $(obj);
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eR7Vs/

Comment: Thanks F. Calderan - I completely missed that one!